# Python Pandas compare two dataframe and keep only data that index appears in both dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe, and would like to keep only row that both matches exactly on index (in this case datetime), and would like to return as two separate dataframe accordingly.

```
df1:
DATETIME,ACCEL_X,ACCEL_Y,ACCEL_Z
2021-10-05 17:04:36,-0.0078125,-0.008544921875,0.9970703125
2021-10-05 17:04:37,0.009521484375,-0.011474609375,0.97900390625
2021-10-05 17:04:38,-0.013427734375,-0.0111083984375,0.9793701171875
2021-10-05 17:04:39,-0.007080078125,0.0028076171875,0.98583984375
2021-10-05 17:04:40,0.012939453125,-0.005615234375,0.996826171875
2021-10-05 17:04:41,-0.0062255859375,0.008056640625,1.0028076171875
2021-10-05 17:04:42,0.0177001953125,-0.001953125,1.0042724609375
2021-10-05 17:04:43,-0.0057373046875,-0.0030517578125,0.99072265625
2021-10-05 17:04:44,0.006103515625,0.0101318359375,1.0035400390625
2021-10-05 17:04:45,0.002197265625,-0.0029296875,0.9827880859375
2021-10-05 17:04:46,-0.001708984375,-0.0045166015625,0.9974365234375
2021-10-05 17:04:47,0.0057373046875,-0.0048828125,0.9930419921875


df2:
DATETIME,ACCEL_X,ACCEL_Y,ACCEL_Z
2021-10-05 17:04:37,-0.03488372093023256,-0.018604651162790697,0.046511627906976744
2021-10-05 17:04:38,-0.006730769230769231,0.0,0.0
2021-10-05 17:04:39,0.02,0.0,0.0
2021-10-05 17:04:40,0.0,0.0,0.0
2021-10-05 17:04:41,0.13653846153846153,0.020192307692307693,-0.10480769230769231
2021-10-05 17:04:42,0.08571428571428572,0.0,0.10571428571428573
2021-10-05 17:04:43,-0.12115384615384615,0.0,-0.06346153846153847
```

Desired output:

```
df1:
DATETIME,ACCEL_X,ACCEL_Y,ACCEL_Z
2021-10-05 17:04:37,0.009521484375,-0.011474609375,0.97900390625
2021-10-05 17:04:38,-0.013427734375,-0.0111083984375,0.9793701171875
2021-10-05 17:04:39,-0.007080078125,0.0028076171875,0.98583984375
2021-10-05 17:04:40,0.012939453125,-0.005615234375,0.996826171875
2021-10-05 17:04:41,-0.0062255859375,0.008056640625,1.0028076171875
2021-10-05 17:04:42,0.0177001953125,-0.001953125,1.0042724609375

df2:
DATETIME,ACCEL_X,ACCEL_Y,ACCEL_Z
2021-10-05 17:04:37,-0.03488372093023256,-0.018604651162790697,0.046511627906976744
2021-10-05 17:04:38,-0.006730769230769231,0.0,0.0
2021-10-05 17:04:39,0.02,0.0,0.0
2021-10-05 17:04:40,0.0,0.0,0.0
2021-10-05 17:04:41,0.13653846153846153,0.020192307692307693,-0.10480769230769231
2021-10-05 17:04:42,0.08571428571428572,0.0,0.10571428571428573
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`align`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.align.html) with `inner` join:

```
new_df1, new_df2 = df1.align(df2, join='inner')
```

*Note this will align *both* index and columns (which works for the provided sample), however, we can also specify the axis to *only* align the index if needed:

```
new_df1, new_df2 = df1.align(df2, join='inner', axis=0)
```

`new_df1`:

```
                      ACCEL_X   ACCEL_Y   ACCEL_Z
DATETIME                                         
2021-10-05 17:04:37  0.009521 -0.011475  0.979004
2021-10-05 17:04:38 -0.013428 -0.011108  0.979370
2021-10-05 17:04:39 -0.007080  0.002808  0.985840
2021-10-05 17:04:40  0.012939 -0.005615  0.996826
2021-10-05 17:04:41 -0.006226  0.008057  1.002808
2021-10-05 17:04:42  0.017700 -0.001953  1.004272
2021-10-05 17:04:43 -0.005737 -0.003052  0.990723
```

`new_df2`:

```
                      ACCEL_X   ACCEL_Y   ACCEL_Z
DATETIME                                         
2021-10-05 17:04:37 -0.034884 -0.018605  0.046512
2021-10-05 17:04:38 -0.006731  0.000000  0.000000
2021-10-05 17:04:39  0.020000  0.000000  0.000000
2021-10-05 17:04:40  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2021-10-05 17:04:41  0.136538  0.020192 -0.104808
2021-10-05 17:04:42  0.085714  0.000000  0.105714
2021-10-05 17:04:43 -0.121154  0.000000 -0.063462
```